# I have a problem installing my node module depandances for Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, node-modules, npm-install

When I do npm install, I get an error at the end:

```
error syscall unlink
22396 error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
22396 error It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
22396 error or that you lack permissions to access it.
22396 error
22396 error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
22396 error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
22396 error the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
22397 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
```

I do not know why

Comment: Sudo in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when that particular file is busy or currently in use.

You can fix this by.

1. Close your code editor and try again
2. Close your any instance of the application if this does not still fix it.
3. Then restart your system to terminate any process that maybe using the file and try again.
4. If you are on a linux or mac machine use `sudo npm install ${package_name}`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

1. open terminal with administrator permission (run as administrator).
2. close all project related files and excute command again.